# Splunk -> two fields not equal to each other

Tags: splunk

I've been googling for how to search in Splunk to find cases where two fields are not equal to each other.

The consensus is to do it like this:

```
index="*"  source="*.csv"   | where Requester!="Requested For"
```

However, this does not work!

This returns results where both Requester and Requested For are equal to "Bob Smith."

Comment: if `Requested For` is the field name then can you please try a single quote? like   `| where Requester!='Requested For'`

Comment: Holy crap, this works! No idea why!! TYSM!

Comment: When you use double quotes, it will treat them as value, like "Requested For" as a value, while you use a single quote 'Requested For' it will search for the filed name with **Requested For** and then consider the value of that field. Please check the below link for more.


https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SCS/current/Search/Quotations

Answer (score 1):

Why not do:

```
index=* source=*.csv Requester=* NOT Requester="Requested For"
```

This ensures there is a `Requester` field present, and that it is not equal to "`Requested For`"

Comment: Apparently `Requested For` is a field name.

Comment: this does not work either :(

Answer (score 0):

If your field name contains a space, then enclose it in single quotes, not double quotes

```
index="*"  source="*.csv"   | where Requester!='Requested For'
```

[Field Names](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SCS/current/Search/Quotations)

> Field names that contain anything other than a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or the underscore ( _ ) character must be enclosed in single quotation marks ( ' ).